# Test if all elements of a list (lists themselves) are equal

Tags: r, list

I have a `list` of lists and want to check whether all elements of this `list` (which are of `list` type) are the same. How to make it in the fastest way?

Update: I put a reproducible example below. The point is to get a `FALSE` value of such a test, because two elements of the `eventual.list` are different: `eventual.list[[1]][[1]]` `data.frame` has other values than `eventual.list[[2]][[1]]` `data.frame`.

Code:

```
a <- 1:3
b <- 1:3
c <- 2:4

l1.el1 <- data.frame(a, b)
l1.el2 <- a
l1 <- list(l1.el1,
           l1.el2)

l2.el1 <- data.frame(a, c)
l2.el2 <- a
l2 <- list(l2.el1,
           l2.el2)

eventual.list <- list(l1,
                      l2)
eventual.list
```

Console output:

```
> eventual.list
[[1]]
[[1]][[1]]
  a b
1 1 1
2 2 2
3 3 3

[[1]][[2]]
[1] 1 2 3


[[2]]
[[2]][[1]]
  a c
1 1 2
2 2 3
3 3 4

[[2]][[2]]
[1] 1 2 3
```

Comment: Can you provide a minimum example? For example, does the list just contain single numeric values or vectors or some other kind of object?

Comment: Hi, thank you for your attention! Yes, the element-lists are supposed to contain objects of different type, e.c. data frames, vectors etc. (See an example I have supplied).

Answer (score 30, accepted):

This is the canonical method for determining whether all items in a list are the same:

```
length(unique(object))==1
```

In your case:

```
> length( unique( eventual.list ) )
[1] 2

> length( unique( eventual.list ) ) == 1
[1] FALSE
```

The help page for `unique` might have led one to think that lists would not be handled, until one reflects on this result that surprised me when I encountered it the first time:

```
 is.vector( eventual.list ) 
[1] TRUE
```

So lists are technically vectors in R parlance, they're just not 'atomic' vectors, they are "recursive".

```
>  is.atomic(eventual.list)
[1] FALSE
> is.recursive(eventual.list)
[1] TRUE
```

Comment: That's a nice idea. Was braking my head on this for half an hour

Comment: Braking is somewhat less violent than breaking or hitting ones head I suppose.